# How to automate wrangling excel data with messy data columns and import into R?

Tags: r, excel

I am working with multiple Excel files. Each file has a set of worksheets with different formats. Each set of worksheets if similar across all the files. I want to combine respective sheet,  so I have only one Excel file with different worksheets. Each Excel file is named according to regions, e.g. regionA.xlsx, regionB.xlsx. However, before combining the respective worksheets together, I need to restructure some of the worksheets into a tidy format, before applying *pivot_longer and map_dfr* functions. The example below shows a generic structure of the input data: the first column includes both the age group, sex and region. The challenge is to group these into different variables.

```r
pop <- tibble::tibble(
'Age, Sex, Region' = c("Rural", "Total (Females)", "0-4", "5-9", NA, "Urban", "Total (Females)", "0-4", "5-9"),
"2011" = c(NA, 104, 55, 49, NA,NA, 175, 100, 75),
"2012" = c(NA, 108, 57, 51, NA,NA,181, 104, 77))

pop
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#>   `Age, Sex, Region` `2011` `2012`
#>   <chr>               <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 Rural                  NA     NA
#> 2 Total (Females)       104    108
#> 3 0-4                    55     57
#> 4 5-9                    49     51
#> 5 <NA>                   NA     NA
#> 6 Urban                  NA     NA
#> 7 Total (Females)       175    181
#> 8 0-4                   100    104
#> 9 5-9                    75     77
```

The desired outcome is shown below before applying the *pivot_longer and map_dfr* functions:

```r
output <- tibble::tibble(
  'age_group' = c("Total (Females)", "0-4", "5-9", "Total (Females)", "0-4", "5-9"),
  'region' = c("Rural", "Rural","Rural","Urban","Urban","Urban"),
  'sex' = c("F","F","F","F","F","F"),
  '2011' = c(104, 55, 49, 175, 100, 75),
  '2012' = c(108, 57, 51, 181, 104, 77),
  'file_id' = c("regionA", "regionA", "regionA", "regionA", "regionA", "regionA"),
  'sheet_id' = c("population", "population", "population", "population", "population", "population"))

output
#> # A tibble: 6 x 7
#>   age_group       region sex   `2011` `2012` file_id sheet_id  
#>   <chr>           <chr>  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>   <chr>     
#> 1 Total (Females) Rural  F        104    108 regionA population
#> 2 0-4             Rural  F         55     57 regionA population
#> 3 5-9             Rural  F         49     51 regionA population
#> 4 Total (Females) Urban  F        175    181 regionA population
#> 5 0-4             Urban  F        100    104 regionA population
#> 6 5-9             Urban  F         75     77 regionA population
```

where regionA is the name of Excel file and population is the name of the worksheet

Comment: I am pretty new to R and still trying to get a handle on which function does what

Comment: This sounds like you could solve this with regex. If the pattern is strictly: age is X-X, sex is in brackets and region is the last one it should be manageable.

Comment: Can you show your expected output for this one dataframe? How do you identify if a value goes in `age_group` or `sex` or `region` ?

Comment: If your purpose is on restructuring your Excel files, you might want to have a look at the `openxlsx` package, which has more powerful functions to deal with Excel files. It looks like you try to copy a frequency table from Excel into R.

Comment: To clarify the question, I have included the desired output. I have tried to use unpivotr, but I cannot wrap my head around it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, I think this will help

### Data

```
pop <- 
  tibble::tibble(
  'age_group' = c("Rural", "Total (Females)", "0-4", "5-9", NA, "Urban", "Total (Females)", "0-4", "5-9"),
  "2011" = c(NA, 104, 55, 49, NA,NA, 175, 100, 75),
  "2012" = c(NA, 108, 57, 51, NA,NA,181, 104, 77)
  )
```

### Code

```
pop %>% 
  filter(!is.na(age_group)) %>% 
  mutate(
    region = if_else(age_group %in% c("Rural","Urban"),age_group,NA_character_),
    sex = case_when(
      str_detect(age_group,"Females") ~ "F",
      str_detect(age_group,"Males") ~ "M",
      TRUE ~ NA_character_
    )
    ) %>% 
  fill(region,sex,.direction = "down") %>% 
  filter(!(age_group %in% c("Rural","Urban"))) %>% 
  select(age_group,region,sex,everything())
```

### Output

```
  age_group       region sex   `2011` `2012`
  <chr>           <chr>  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Total (Females) Rural  F        104    108
2 0-4             Rural  F         55     57
3 5-9             Rural  F         49     51
4 Total (Females) Urban  F        175    181
5 0-4             Urban  F        100    104
6 5-9             Urban  F         75     77
```